# How to prevent CPU governor from changing automatically on laptop power?

Tags: xubuntu, power-management

I noticed when I plug-in or unplug my laptop's AC adapter, the CPU scaling governor changes to ondemand.
Because my laptop gets fairly hot, and I do nothing intensive on it, I prefer powersave at all times... and it helps keep my lap cool.

Is there a way to prevent Xubuntu from automatically changing it to ondemand when I plug/unplug the AC adapter?

I'm using Xubuntu 12.10 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a silly pm script that is doing this but I don't know it off the top of my head. If you militantly want to stick to powersave, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo install -b -m 744 <(<<EOF
#! /bin sh

sleep 5

for CPUFREQ in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
do
    [ -f $CPUFREQ ] || continue
    echo -n powersave > $CPUFREQ
done
EOF) /etc/pm/power.d/99-powersave
```

The embedded script there will then run whenever your power situation changes. We don't really need to target the `on_ac_power` event at all. This will just set powersave whenever it can.

It sleeps for five seconds before running just in case whatever is setting it to ondemand takes a little while to trigger.

Comment: What's that line at the beginning of the script ?